# Intel Assembly Can't Find Argv Address

Tags: assembly

I don't know if this is a broad question or not, but I'm having a hard time finding the argument vector strings.  Here is my GDB output.

```
(gdb) run test
Starting program: /root/Desktop/booksrc/a.out test
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe468) at convert2.c:14
14      count = atoi(argv[2]); // convert the 2nd arg into an integer
(gdb) x/3xw 0x7fffffffe468
0x7fffffffe468: 0xffffe6d2  0x00007fff  0xffffe6ee
(gdb) x/3xw 0xffffe6d2
0xffffe6d2: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffe6d2
(gdb) x/3xw 0x00007fff
0x7fff: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff
```

So what should be my first argument, `/root/Desktop/booksrc/a.out` is unreachable, as well as the test argument.  What gives?

Comment: You are in 64 bit mode, your pointers are 64 bit. In any case you can just to `p argv[2]` and forget about that detail.

Comment: The source that I am reading uses 32 bit.  However, why are the addresses unreachable?  Is it a formatting issue?

Comment: Unreachable because you only used the low half of them. If you want to play in 32 bit mode, compile using `gcc -m32`.

Comment: Is there a command to make examine output give the first 4 bytes that I was missing?  So x/3xw would give me 0x7fffffffe6d2 instead of 0xffffe6d2?  And thanks so much for the help, I didn't realize that 64 would have different addressing mechanics :P

Comment: You can use the `/a` format, or put the two halves together yourself, which have been printed already: `0x7fffffffe468: 0xffffe6d2  0x00007fff` so `0x00007fffffffe6d2`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `g` instead of `w` in your command.  `g` stands for "giant" or 8bytes, and since your on a 64bit machine, instead of `x/3xw` you want `x/3xg` and you will get something like this:

```
(gdb) x/3xg 0x7fff5fbff900
0x7fff5fbff900: 0x00007fff5fbffa38  0x00007fff5fbffa6a
0x7fff5fbff910: 0x0000000000000000
```

Then `x/s 0x00007fff5fbffa38` and you will see the argv argument which is the path of your program and the second `0x00007fff5fbffa6a` would be "test".